# Pandas: With array of col names in a desired column order, select those that exist, NULL those that don't

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

- I have an array of column names I want as my output table in that order e.g. `["A", "B", "C"]`
- I have an input table that **USUALLY** contains all of the values in the array but **NOT ALWAYS** (the raw data is a JSON API response).
- I want to select all available columns from the input table, and if a column does not exist, I want it filled with NULLs or NA or whatever, it doesn't really matter.

Let's say my input DataFrame (call it `input_table`) looks like this:

```
+-----+--------------+
|  A  |      C       |
+-----+--------------+
| 123 | test         |
| 456 | another_test |
+-----+--------------+
```

I want an output dataframe that has columns `A, B, C` in that order to produce

```
+-----+------+--------------+
|  A  |  B   |      C       |
+-----+------+--------------+
| 123 | NULL | test         |
| 456 | NULL | another_test |
+-----+------+--------------+
```

- I get a keyerror when I do `input_table[["A","B","C"]]`
- I get a NoneType returned when I do `input_table.get(["A","B","C"])`

I was able to achieve what I want via:

```
for i in desired_columns_array:
    if i not in input_dataframe:
        ouput_dataframe[i] = ""
    else:
        output_dataframe[i] = input_dataframe[i]
```

But I'm wondering if there's something less verbose?

How do I get a desired output schema to match an input array when one or more columns in the input dataframe may not be present?

Answer (score 0):

Transpose and reindex

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[123,'test'], [456, 'another test']], columns=list('AC'))

l = list('ACB')
df1 = df.T.reindex(l).T[sorted(l)]

     A    B             C
0  123  NaN          test
1  456  NaN  another test
```

Answer (score 0):

`DataFrame.reindex` over the column axis:

```
cols = ['A', 'B', 'C']
df.reindex(cols, axis='columns')
     A   B             C
0  123 NaN          test
1  456 NaN  another_test
```